# EJBQL - Find all rows that have more than 'x' relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, ejbql

I know there must be a simple way to do this, but it's not coming to me at the moment.  I've got a simple entity like (irrelevant parts removed for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reviews")
public class Review {
    private String text;
    private boolean approved;
    private Collection<ReviewFlag> flags;

    public Review() {
        this.text = null;
        this.approved = false;
        this.flags = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="review")
    public Collection<ReviewFlag> getFlags() {
        return flags;
    }
}
```

I want to run a query that finds every unapproved review with two or more flags.  Something like:

```
SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.approved = 0 AND COUNT(r.flags) > 1
```

...but of course that syntax doesn't work (hibernate complains about syntax).  I've tried it as:

```
SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.approved = 0 HAVING COUNT(r.flags) > 1
```

...that one runs, but also returns reviews that have 0 or 1 flags.  What's the magic invocation I need to use to find only the ones with 2 or more flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of annotations I assume you operate in such an environment where JPQL can be used instead of EJB QL. If so, then [SIZE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_arithmetic) operator is there for this kind of purpose. It takes path to collection as argument and returns number of elements.

In your case JPQL query is:

```
SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.approved = 0 AND SIZE(r.flags) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(f.review) FROM Flag f WHERE f.review.hidden = 0 AND f.review.approved = 0 GROUP BY f.review HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

A bit more obtuse than I'd like, but it works.

Note to self:  stop answering own questions.